# Where are Xdebug configurations set outside of the php.ini? (Windows 10)

Tags: phpstorm, php-8, xdebug-3

Running PHP 8 with PhpStorm version 2020.3.3, on Windows 10. When I use Xdebug3 as my debugger, I am able to use breakpoints successfully, but I get an annoying message every time:

```
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_host' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_host (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_mode' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_mode (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_port' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_port (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
```

Going to the doc gives me helpful notes of configurations that have changed in Xdebug with Xdebug 3, however, I am not able to find these settings in my PHP 8 php.ini. In the PHP 8 php.ini, the Xdebug section's configs seem to match those recommended in the documentation:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\PHP\php 8\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

When I run `phpinfo()` on a file, the output on the XDEBUG section reads below:

```
Version => 3.0.4
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

           Enabled Features<br/>(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)           
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Aids => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key => 18658

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.output_dir => C:\Windows\Temp => C:\Windows\Temp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => trigger => trigger
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Is there another place that these configs are set, where I can change them to get rid of the annoying error messages??

Comment: 1) What do you debug when you see that message? A CLI script or a web page? In any case: capture `phpinfo()` output in the same way as you are trying to debug and see what config files PHP is using (will be at he very top). Then just go trough those files and find all matches where `xdebug.` is used and look for those Xdebug v2 entries.

Comment: 2) If it's a CLI script debug (e.g.PHPUnit test or whatnot) then it might be the PhpStorm itself. Double check that PhpStorm is aware of Xdebug v3 in PHP Interpreter settings.Check the `Console` tab of the Debugger in such case and see what command PhpStorm is using to launch the PHP / your script. It may be sending both v2 and v3 params at the same time for you (does not do that for me; running PhpStorm 2020.3.3 on Windows 10)

Comment: @LazyOne That might be worth adding as an answer, since you've pretty much covered all the possibilities there I think.

Comment: @IMSoP There are still other options available: 1) Xdebug environment variable (that can contain such config) -- I just not sure how Xdebug reacts if they come from there. This is normally in use with Docker or alike. 2) An option gets set in the actual PHP code during runtime for some reason -- I have seen that a few times (once here on SO and 2 or 3 times on PhpStorm Forums). No idea why it was used like that in the first place, but it worked for the person that did that back then ... and then, year or so later it made issues for another dev :)